# Statusbar not showing for other screens in Flutter if Splashscreen is added

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

After added SplashScreen in `Flutter`, Statusbar not showing in the main activity.

**If I open style.xml**

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

issue arrise because of this = > 
**`<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>`**

**How to set full screen only for SplashScreen and show status bar for all other screens?**

**flutter code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sixbrix/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
      title: 'Flutter',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: createMaterialColor(Color(0xFFD96332)),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter App'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text("Hello"),
    );
  }
}

MaterialColor createMaterialColor(Color color) {
  List strengths = <double>[.05];
  Map swatch = <int, Color>{};
  final int r = color.red, g = color.green, b = color.blue;

  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    strengths.add(0.1 * i);
  }
  strengths.forEach((strength) {
    final double ds = 0.5 - strength;
    swatch[(strength * 1000).round()] = Color.fromRGBO(
      r + ((ds < 0 ? r : (255 - r)) * ds).round(),
      g + ((ds < 0 ? g : (255 - g)) * ds).round(),
      b + ((ds < 0 ? b : (255 - b)) * ds).round(),
      1,
    );
  });
  return MaterialColor(color.value, swatch);
}
```

Comment: Have you removed **<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>**? If yes, can you drop your flutter code?

Comment: If I removed `android:windowFullscreen` then statusbar displaying in SplashScreen also.

Comment: statusbar displaying in SplasgScreen won't show again?

Comment: Can you drop your flutter code?

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi Code added.

Comment: I don't won't to show statusbar on splash screen. If I add `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>` in android style, it hides statusbar. But issue is it is not showing statusbar after splashscreen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209834/discussion-between-josteve-adekanbi-and-chirag-savsani).

Answer (score 2):

Try out my below code

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; 

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values); //add this line 
   return Scaffold(
   backgroundColor: Colors.white,
   body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset(
          'images/splash_logo.png',
          width: 50.0,
          height: 100.0,
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10.0,
        ),
        Text(
          "Any",
          ),
        ),
      ],
     ),
    ),
  );
}
```

this one for more info :

```
// to hide only bottom bar:
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([SystemUiOverlay.top]);

// to hide only status bar: 
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);

// to hide both:
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([]);
```

Comment: @ChiragSavsani did you removed style.xml stuff before trying this code?

Comment: If I use this code instead of inbuilt splash screen, it is showing blank screen first and then splash screen display.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>` and try this.

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Hello"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Home Screen"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ignore my implementation of splash screen, I just wanted something that will navigate to another page that was why I used FAB

Answer (score 0):

You should write a MethodChannel, just like:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static void showHideStatusBar(boolean show, Activity activity){
    if (show == false){
        View decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        // Hide Status Bar.
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        Log.e("flutter","隐藏statusBar");
    }else{
        activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
        Log.e("flutter","显示statusBar");

    }
}
```

and call this native method in your "initState" method!